# System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot find column named Party_Name

Tags: c#, ms-access

I get a not found error even though the table exists in the database. How can I solve this problem?

```
 private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            Aconnection.Open();
            int selectedRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex];
            string parti_Name = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["Parti_Name"].Value); //Parti = Party(in English)
            string oy_Oran = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["Oy_Oran"].Value);       //oy = Vote      / Oran = Rate (in English)

            OleDbCommand cmd = Aconnection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO OY (Parti_Name, Oy_Oran) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parti_Name", parti_Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Oy_Oran", oy_Oran);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Aconnection.Close();
        }
```

[DataAccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c066K.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMl7f.png)

I tried different ways but still got the same error.

Comment: change your INSERT statement to mention the parameter names instead of just "?" symbol.  like this cmd.CommandText = `"INSERT INTO OY (Parti_Name, Oy_Oran) VALUES (@Parti_Name, @Oy_Oran)"`. You are mentioning only 2 column names, then no need to pass 3 "?" symbols.

Comment: I fixed it but the same problem persists again.

Comment: then, check the connection string used for `Aconnection`, and verify if it is correctly connecting to your database.

Comment: Also, you have not supplied OleDbConnection to your command object !? is that line `OleDbCommand cmd = Aconnection.CreateCommand();` doing it ? unless you share what createCommand does, we don't know.

Comment: My aim was to save the value entered from the datagrid to the database.

Comment: On which line is the error thrown?

Comment: In the string party_name line

Comment: That means that the column Parti_Name does not exist in your `DataGridView`, it has nothing to do with the `INSERT`. To check the column names, put a break on this line and examine selectedRows.Cells[0]..[n] . where n is the Columns Count -1. Check the Properties. This will reveal the error

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have made a correct connection to your access database, you should be able to execute the parameterized INSERT statement.
You have *not* mentioned the parameter names in your INSERT sql statement. Change your INSERT statement so as to mention the parameter names instead of just the "?" symbol.

Like this

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO OY (Parti_Name, Oy_Oran) 
                     VALUES (@Parti_Name, @Oy_Oran)";
```

Also, you are having only 2 column names in the INSERT statement, then no need to pass 3 "?" symbols.